# Invalid params for rpc

Tags: rpc, json-rpc

I am writing runtime rpc with multiple parameters:

```
#[rpc]
pub trait ShivarthuApi<BlockHash> {
    #[rpc(name = "shivarthu_challengerevidence")]
    fn get_challengers_evidence(
        &self,
        at: Option<BlockHash>,
        profile_citizenid: u128,
        offset: u64,
        limit: u16,
    ) -> Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>>;
}
```

It successfully compiled, but gives invalid params error when called through curl

```
curl http://localhost:9933 -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8" -d   '{
     "jsonrpc":"2.0",
      "id":1,
      "method":"shivarthu_challengerevidence",
      "params": [0, 3, 5]
    }'
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32602,"message":"Invalid params: invalid type: number, expected a (both 0x-prefixed or not) hex string with length of 64."},"id":1}
```

rpc call with named parameters

```
curl http://localhost:9933 -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8" -d   '{
     "jsonrpc":"2.0",
      "id":1,
      "method":"shivarthu_challengerevidence",
      "params": {"profile_citizenid" :0, "offset": 2, "limit":5}
    }'
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32602,"message":"Invalid params: invalid type: map, expected a tuple of size 4."},"id":1}
```

Comment: It works with "params": [null,0, 3, 5]

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message above,

`Invalid params: invalid type: number, expected a (both 0x-prefixed or not) hex string with length of 64.`

This is for the `BlockHash` parameter, you need to pass an actual hash, i.e. `0x123...def` would be applicable. Or `null` if the `Option` is empty, any non-null value needs to be a valid `BlockHash`.

(Generally you most-probably would like to move the `Option` parameters to the end, or at least that is the pattern followed in Substrate)